# How to link a C library to an Assembly library on Mac with clang

Tags: macos, c, dynamic-linking, x86, assembly

I have this in my C library:

```
myc:
    @clang -I . -dynamiclib \
        -undefined dynamic_lookup \
        -o myc.dylib myc.c
.PHONY: myc
```

And this in my assembly library:

```
buildasm:
  @nasm -f macho64 myasm.asm
  @clang -o myasm myasm.o myc.dylib
  # @ld -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 \
  #   -lSystem -o myasm \
  #   myasm.o
  @./myasm
.PHONY: buildasm
```

I would like to then have a third either assembly or C *project* which loads the assembly library. But I can't get this C -> assembly working. I also don't have `dyld` the "dynamic loader" on Mac installed, so if possible I would prefer not to install any special tools, but if required I would like to know how to do the linking with the tool.

If I make the `buildasm` into this:

```
buildasm:
  @nasm -f macho64 myasm.asm
  @ld -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 \
    -lSystem -o myasm \
    myasm.o myc.dylib
  @./myasm
.PHONY: buildasm
```

it compiles without any errors, but when it runs with `./myasm` it gives:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "my_c_function", referenced from:
      start in myasm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

If I do this basically in asm:

```
extern my_c_function

start:
  call my_c_function
```

And something like this in C:

```
extern void my_c_function() {

}
```

Wondering what would make this work.

Comment: Dynamic libraries are not embedded in the binary they need to be found and loaded at runtime. For that certain search paths apply and current directory is not one of them. Not sure about macos, but google says you could do `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./myasm`. You almost certainly have `dyld` installed as that is required for any programs using dynamic libraries. See also `man dyld`.

Comment: Don't you mean `extern _my_c_function` `call _my_c_function` since the _C_ functions will be decorated with a leading underscore when using macho objects?